# AngularFireStorage error [object object]

Tags: javascript, angular, web

al declarar la variable private en el constructor, esta me arroja el error y no me carga la vista

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {incidenciasService} from '../service/incidencias.service';
import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';




@Component({
 selector: 'registroSap-component',
 templateUrl: './registroSap.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./registro.component.css']
})
export class registroSapComponent {
incidencia:any = {estado:"nuevo", tipo:"sap"};


 constructor(private incidenciaService:incidenciasService , private afStorage: AngularFireStorage){}

 Upload(event){
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  const randomId = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
  const task = this.afStorage.upload(`images/${randomId}`, file);
  this.incidencia.image = randomId;
 }

 guardarIncidencia(){

  this.incidencia.id = Date.now();
  if (this.incidencia.titulo && this.incidencia.departamento && this.incidencia.usuario && this.incidencia.descripcion) {
  this.incidenciaService.guardarIncidencias(this.incidencia);
  alert("¡Incidencia guardada exitosamente!");
  this.incidencia = {};

}else{
  alert("Complete los campos por favor.");
}

}

}
```

aqui anexo el error que me sale en la consola
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si quito esta linea de codigo, no me sale el error pero necesito eso!

```
 private afStorage: AngularFireStorage
```